# No "Directory" or "File" in System.IO

Tags: c#, .net

I've just started to use new VS2012 and Windows 8 and create C# Metro-style project. I want to get list of files in directory, but string "Directory.GetFiles(path)" invoke an error saying it doesn't exist in current context. But I use System.IO.
The only useful thing I have in System.IO is "Path" - no "Directory" or "File" there. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 8 Metro-Style apps do not support the filesystem.

Instead, use the [new Metro APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh758319%28v=win.10%29.aspx).